# Chartjs wont render a graph from datetime.datetime code requested from mysql database in Django using views.py

Tags: django, datetime, chart.js

I cant figure out how to render a simple trend line in chartjs using datatime.datetime data from a mysql database.

I have polled two rows of a table I want to use to create a line graph in chartjs. Data in the form of temperature and datetime when the temperature was recorded.

When I look at the script it shows the temperature data is fine and can be used but the format the datetime row is in wont allow x-axis labels

Below is an example of the array retrieved from the database using a function in views.

```
[
  datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 7, 18, 32, 5, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 7, 18, 32, 16, tzinfo=<UTC>)
],**
```

The error in the code
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

**models.py**

```
class Mqtt(models.Model):
    createdat = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt')  
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    qos = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'mqtt'
```

**views.py**

```
 def chart_red(request):
    labels = []
    data = []
    chart_red_obj = Mqtt.objects.order_by('createdat')[:2] 
    for mqtt in chart_red_obj:

    labels.append(mqtt.createdat)
    data.append(mqtt.message)

    return render(request, "chart_red.html", {
    'labels':labels,
    'data':data,
     })
})
```

**html and js**

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  <script>
    var temp = {
      type: 'line',

      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: {{ data|safe }},
          label: 'Trend'
        }],
        labels:{{ labels|safe }},
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true
      }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, temp);
    };
```

When I view the code in the developer tools it looks like below. No Chart

```
  </script>
   var config = {
      type: 'line',
       data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: ['65.3', '65.3'],
          label: 'Trend'
        }],
        **labels:[datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 7, 18, 32, 5, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 7, 18, 32, 16, tzinfo=<UTC>)],**
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true
      }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

I have the MatPlot lib solution for this trend so if the question is not clear don't worry, will do it the easy way and leave Chartjs to the professionals

Comment: Just saying "it doesn't work" is no use to us. You need to explain what doesn't work, hwat you get and what you expect to get. Even with the code you've provided without an example of the input message it's useless.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, this is my first time using the site. The model I created is for the data coming over mqtt. Very basic structure with date, topic and message. The message is a temperature. I want to render the data using chartjs in a line graph with the tempertaure and the date. The view.py code should be enough to do this but the datetime structure is ** datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 7, 18, 32, 5, tzinfo=<UTC>) ** . Chartjs cant use it. How do I make this datetime information useful on the x axis?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66622986/edit) the question to add details. And add the actual message content, not a description of it